# England team win senior 50+ world team championships and all the board golds - first time ever?

Tags: history, records, world-championship, chess-olympiad, senior-chess

In this year's FIDE World Senior Team 50+ Championship the [England team won](https://www.fide.com/news/1839) the tournament and won all four board gold medals:

> England 1, headed by Michael Adams and Nigel Short, won all four matches in the second half of the event and deservedly clinched the title. To illustrate England’s dominance, it suffices to say that Adams, Short, Hebden and Arkell each won the gold medal for the best performance on individual boards.

[image: England senior 50+ team]

Is this the first time a team has done this at world team championship or Olympiad level? The USSR teams must have come close during the Soviet period.